# Calendar control thats work in all browser

Tags: c#, calendar

I've previously used an Ajax calendar control, but it's not working in the Mozilla Firefox browser. I need a calendar control either in JavaScript or any control in asp.net with source code that's supported in all the browsers.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery UI has a nice calendar control that works in all browsers (have used in IE6-9, FireFox, Chrome, Safari and Opera).

Are there specific features you are looking for?

[jQuery UI - DatePicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/)

Answer (score 0):

I use [Eyecon datepicker](http://www.eyecon.ro/datepicker/)

Tested on Firefox, IE 7.0 8.0 and 9.0 Safari and Chrome. Requires jQuery. It's GPL.

Comment: one textbox nearby one image when i click the image calendar should popup......can u send for this a jquery......